# Best way to update Rails model with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an Rails app with a survey form which passes the responses as JSON format. Creation of answers works fine, however not quite sure how to approach the update.

Survey has got answers in the survey_answers table. Survey_answer has user_id, survey_id, question_id and response fields. That means however that every survey_answer is a separate record.

I can access the specific response through something like
`SurveyAnswer.where(user_id: 1, survey_id: 1, question_id: 1).response`
and update through that but then again, not sure how to handle it with JSON.

What do you think it's the best way to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the json to the Survey endpoint. Add accepts_nested_attributes for survey_answers to survey. Structure the json so that it looks like so:

```
{
  survey: {
    name: '',
    survey_answer_attributes: [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  {
}
```

White list the nested params. [Basically RTFM](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).